Are people born or do they become selfish?
The majority of the people are selfish.But do we become selfish or are we born selfish?Does the upbringing influence that or are people inherently bad?
I can think of some cases which makes a person selfish for example certain emotions (when we achieve something good we want to achieve it again so we learn to disregard the feelings of others) but im not sure if this is the only factor.

The short answer to any "nature versus nurture" question is always "both". That said, learning is huge: https://nautil.us/selfishness-is-learned-235965/
